# Use JavaScript fetch to display content in a part of page but JavaScript is not connected with it anymore

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am using fetch to display content on the page so the page do not refresh. But the problem here is that the file I am getting in fetch request is connected with style but not with JavaScript file. The functionalities are not working any more, there are some buttons in the fetched file which I want to be clickable so they can fetch an other file. Further if I try to select the element which I have fetched using querySelector there will be error like null. Like there is not any element there yet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!-- :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: style sheets ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />

    <!-- ::::::::::::::::::::::::::: script ::::::::::::::::::::::: -->

    <script defer src="/main.js"></script>

    <title>Websit-A2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="log-content" id="inner-card"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my index.html code

```
const contentDiv = document.getElementById("inner-card");

window.onload = (e) => {
  fetch("./html-files/H1-login.html")
    .then((Response) => Response.text())
    .then((html) => {
      contentDiv.innerHTML = html;
    });
};
```

This is JavaScript which is fetching a file named H1-login.html onload window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!-- :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: style sheets ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles-sheets/S1-login.css" />

    <!-- ::::::::::::::::::::::::::: script ::::::::::::::::::::::: -->

    <script defer src="/JS-files/J1-login.js"></script>

    <title>Websit-A2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="log-content" id="inner-card">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Login here!</h1>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form">
        <div class="field">
          <input type="email" required />
          <span>Email :</span>
          <i></i>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <input type="password" required />
          <span>Password :</span>
          <i></i>
        </div>
        <div class="btns">
          <button class="forgot btn" data-category="H3-forgot">
            forgot password
          </button>
          <button class="register btn" data-category="H2-registration">
            register here
          </button>
        </div>
        <button class="submit">submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is the HTML file which is been loading and this file is also connected to JavaScript file for more functionalities, but these functionalities are not working in index.html

Comment: Script written into the DOM with `.innerHTML` do not get executed as far as I know - it's unsafe and could contain user scripts which would run with full privileges. You need to structure your JS code so it can either detect HTML content added to the page that it needs to act on (using a, say, `MutationObserver`) or you need to load the script and execute it explicitly by making a `script` and appending it to the page.

Comment: still i could not accomplish what i am trying

Comment: Great. Still, I couldn’t tell you more about approach. Rethink your strategy here.

Comment: i am trying to solve this from 3days but faild. what i want here is that i made seperate file for forgot,signup and signin when the index page loads it fetch login file and in login file there are buttons of forgot and sign and this file is connected with js file for functionality but when the file is been fetched in index no js script runs which was connected with signin file or any file which feched

Comment: i appreciate your help, you might understand what i am trying to do here if there is any other approach to do that please guide me

Comment: I understand your issue and the silution is to either load in the script seperarely after your html, or having a global script loaded that you can then just call.

Comment: This script will be ommitted if you `.innerHTML` your content: `<script defer src="/JS-files/J1-login.js"></script>` - it just won't be executed due to security concerns. So you need to load this separately. In general though, you shouldn't couple the script like that. You should have one script for your site which can handle it all and be called when necessary. A function, for example, that load the HTML and then immediately executes all the stuff you want so you can just call one method like `displayLogin()` or something... Your approach is just a bit... 1999.